# how to create a subplots in python using seaborn or matplotlib inside for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to create subplots inside for loop for various columns of the dataset. I am using the California housing dataset from sklearn. So, there are 4 columns and I want to display three figures for each column in a subplot. I have provided the code which I have tried. Can somebody help me with this issue? Can we make it dynamic so that if I need to add more figure then we can add easily with title?

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_california_housing
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

california_housing = fetch_california_housing(as_frame=True)
# california_housing.frame.head()
features_of_interest = ["AveRooms", "AveBedrms", "AveOccup", "Population"]
california_housing.frame[features_of_interest]

fig, axes = plt.subplots(4, 3)

for cols in features_of_interest:
    # scatterplot
    sns.scatterplot(x=california_housing.frame[cols], y=california_housing.target)
    # histogram
    sns.histplot(x=california_housing.frame[cols], y=california_housing.target)
    #qqplot
    sm.qqplot(california_housing.frame[cols], line='45')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: If my post did not answer your question, let me know what are you looking! I can make some improvements and you can accept it! :-)

Answer (score 3):

There are some problems with your code:

- you need to import statsmodels.api as sm
- you need to use the ax parameter from scatterplot, histplot, and qqplot to indicate where the plot will be present
- the way that you load the data isnot allowing matplotlib and seaborn to use the data. I made some changes on this part.
- you do not need to show on each iteration just at the end.

```py
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_california_housing
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.api as sm

california_housing = fetch_california_housing(as_frame=True).frame
features_of_interest = ["AveRooms", "AveBedrms", "AveOccup", "Population"]

fig, axes = plt.subplots(len(features_of_interest), 3)

for i, cols in enumerate(features_of_interest):
    # scatterplot
    sns.scatterplot(x=california_housing[cols], y=california_housing['MedHouseVal'], ax=axes[i,0])
    # histogram
    sns.histplot(x=california_housing[cols], y=california_housing['MedHouseVal'], ax=axes[i,1])
    #qqplot
    sm.qqplot(california_housing[cols], line='45', ax=axes[i,2])

plt.show()
```

PS.: I used len(features_of_interest) to auto-adapt our script considering the number of features.

Comment: Hi Greogory, 
The code is taking forever to run. Is it the same issue with you? I am running code in Jupyter notebook and it is still running.

Comment: I use Kaggle notebook to code it. I will share the notebook later and send you the link. I run perfectly.

Comment: https://www.kaggle.com/code/gregoryoliveira/draftbook-stackoverflow

Comment: Thank you. It started to work now. I had a problem with VS code.